# Are there any Ubiquity System blogs?

Tags: ubiquity, hollow-earth-expedition

There are many D&D, Pathfinder or generic RPG blogs, but are there any Ubiquity System or *Hollow Earth Expedition* blogs out there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blogs for Ubiquity can be found at:

- [Sechin Tower](http://www.sechintower.com/blog/), as mentioned by [Nestor](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7786/are-there-any-ubiquity-system-blogs/7792#7792) has great material for running pulp adventures
- [The Black Campbell](http://blackcampbell.wordpress.com/role-playing-game-related/hollow-earth-expedition-page/)'s blog has entries on Ubiquity in general and HEX in particular from time to time. He tends to produce posts on how to run games, play reports, and gear stats.
- [Casting Shadows](http://runeslinger.wordpress.com/tag/ubiquity/), my blog, has a slowly growing collection of material for HEX, All for One, and Desolation. I tend to post entries on using the system, running heroic pulp action games, adventure seeds, and settings.

Resources for Ubiquity can be found at:

- [Mythic Eras](http://www.mythiceras.net/), although it does not have blog articles per se. The site has a forum, and links to adventures, alternate rules and settings, and the Danger Magnet magazine.
- The Hollow Earth Expedition page of John Kahane's Emporium used to have a wealth of links to all sorts of useful resources, such as specific historical information for the period. It is sadly no longer available.
- Each line has its own forum as well, where lots of information can be shared and discussed:

  - [HEX](http://www.exilegames.com/forum/index.php)
  - [Desolation](http://greymalkindesigns.com/phpBB3/index.php)
  - [All for One: Regime Diabolique](http://www.tripleacegames.com/forum/index.php?c=4&sid=951786e68de1792e2ce30a3dde8446f9)

Comment: Mythic Eras is currently down for renovation

Comment: Mythic Eras is back!

Comment: exilegames.com is dead

Answer (score 4):

A german Ubiquity-Blog called [ubiHEX](http://ubihex.blogspot.com).

Answer (score 2):

Sechin Tower, whose a lead developer for Exile Games, has a writer's [blog](http://www.sechintower.com/blog/) that includes material about pulp gaming with HEX and in general. That's one.